# python large-data multiprocessing failure

Tags: python, multiprocessing, large-data

my python code in windows with  *multiprocessing.Pool* by running *.py* file, for smaller chuck of data runs correctly but for large-data size, also runs before it gives output of each pool and then it gives this error what should I do? I have not thing to say more and sorry stackoverflow didn't let me to put this long error in the code format
error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-4:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-10:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-6:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-8:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-7:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-9:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
Process SpawnPoolWorker-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 131, in worker
    put((job, i, result))
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 362, in put
    obj = _ForkingPickler.dumps(obj)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
MemoryError
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 315, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 108, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 133, in worker
    wrapped = MaybeEncodingError(e, result[1])
  File "C:\Users\USER GOOD\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.value = repr(value)
MemoryError
```

the code is like this

```
import math
import os
import numpy as np
import time
import multiprocessing
import csv
def dadesazlistfake11(dlist):
    ...some data manupilation...
    return zlist ###gives an np array
def subu(remo,slist):
    rawnp=np.zeros(1) ##in order to release some memory from each pool
    periodend=len(slist)-24
    remlist=dadesazlistfake11(slist[575-575:575+25])
    for l in range(576,periodend):
        remlist=np.vstack((remlist,dadesazlistfake11(slist[l-575:l+25])))
        if (l-576)%4000==0:
            print(f'{remo,l-575}')
            ftime=time.perf_counter()
            print(f'in{ftime-stime}s finished')
    return remlist
```

columha and splito are some intiliazed arrays/lists

```
columha=[[],[],[],[]]
s=0
l=0
###creating columha
...
##columha is some 4*75 array
def splito(a,b,c,d,e):
    #bazehaye entehaei nemikhahim tu loop bashan
    period=np.zeros(e+1).astype(int)
    period[0]= a+c-1 #575
    period[e]= b-d-1 #489688
    delta=int(math.floor((period[e]-period[0])/e))
    for i in range(1,e):
        period[i]=period[0]+i*delta
    return period
```

reading data:

```
os.chdir(r'C:\Users\...')
my_file = open("dsa.csv", 'r')
reader = csv.reader(my_file, delimiter=',')
rawlist = list(reader)
rawlist=rawlist[1:len(rawlist)]
for i in range(len(rawlist)):
    rawlist[i]=rawlist[i][2:]
    for j in range(len(rawlist[i])):
        rawlist[i][j]=float(rawlist[i][j])
rawlist=rawlist[0:800] ##small version
rawnp=np.asarray(rawlist)
rawlist=[] ##in order to release some memory
```

start of code:

```
thread_num=10
period=splito(0,len(rawnp),96*6,24,thread_num)
tupleinput=[tuple([i,rawnp[period[i]-575:period[i+1]+24]]) for i in range(thread_num)]
stime=time.perf_counter()
if __name__=="__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(thread_num) as pool:
        wholelist = list(pool.starmap(subu,tupleinput))
#         wholenp = np.vstack((wholenp,pool.starmap(subu,tupleinput)))
    rawnp=np.zeros(1) ##in order to release some memory 
    shape0=-1,869
#     wholenp=np.asarray(wholelist[0])#.reshape(shape0)
    wholenp=wholelist[0]
    for i in range(1,len(wholelist)):
#         wholenp=np.vstack((wholenp,np.asarray(wholelist[i]).reshape(shape0)))
        wholenp=np.vstack((wholenp,wholelist[i]))
        wholelist[i]=np.zeros(1)
#         wholelist[i]=[]
    print('lennp',len(wholenp))
    ftime=time.perf_counter()
    print(f'total process in{ftime-stime}s finished')
    input()
```

I also tried the code with just 3 cores and the same error happened

Comment: it seems you spawn too many processes. In any case it seems system runs out of memory

Comment: 1) share the code 2) how many cores do you have?

Comment: @NikosM. so what should I do? lower the processes? doesn't the virtual memoty help?

Comment: @balderman 12logical cores using just 10 of them

Comment: slice the data into smaller chunks and feed the core with smaller data

Comment: @balderman here I can, but later on I may won't be able to do this, so I need a solution and pls see the code is added

Comment: @NikosM. I have tried to release them when it's possible, see the code

Comment: @balderman what should I do about it? I didn't get an answer. how can I move up my question to be seen more in stackoverflow?

Comment: @tdelaney Hi u seem to have worked with multiprocessing, do u know any solutions?

Comment: @FarhangAmaji Few options: 1) work in smaller chunks (if possible) 2) buy more memory  :-) 3) use distributed solution like Apache Spark